# WordPress Permalink - GCP Load Balancer - 503

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, google-cloud-platform, permalinks, google-cloud-load-balancer

Everything works fine until I sent permalink to %postname%.

I have tried everything like AllowOverride All in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf.

Nothing works and it gives me 503.

I didn't find in solution online which works in 2023.

File: .htaccess

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Your post lacks details to answer correctly. The type of web server, the type of hosting, what documentation you followed? Is the load Balancer configured correctly? Can you share the correct error you're observing?   503 error means server temporarily not available or service unavailable which might occur if your domain name is not linked properly to your IP address or server overloading also.

Comment: Meanwhile  You can try the following strategies and refer to this [blog](https://themeisle.com/blog/fix-503-error-wordpress/#gref) authored by Sufia Banu  to fix it: Turn off your plugins, Change your theme, Reinstall WordPress, Upgrade your hosting account, Check if the [CPU and memory limits are exceeded.](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/503-error-when-activating-any-new-plugin/) Post Enable Apache AllowOverride, After you’ve made changes, make sure to restart the server: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries